# PID number in Task Manager can't be found

Tags: task-manager, pid

i tried running `netstat -o` to check what are the connections which are established. I saw two and they have PID numbers. When I checked it in my Task Manager, I couldn't find those PID numbers.
Is there any way to find them?

Comment: Have you selected the "show processes from all users" button/checkbox? Presumably you're running Windows - what version?

Comment: Is it possible that the tasks have simply terminated between the netstat and the launch of Task Manager?

Comment: @DMA5736: how can i show all processes from all users? i'm running windows 7

Comment: Press the button indicated in [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/11322d1242721091-task-manager-create-elevated-shortcut-unelevated.jpg) image, as found [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/10499-task-manager-create-elevated-shortcut.html) (because I'm not on a Win7 machine at the moment to make my own screenshot).

Comment: @DMA5736: i saw it and the other PID represent the spooler subsystem app. and the number 4 represents for the "System" not sure what they are doing in my PC as they represent established. I was suspecting that this might a keylogger or so...

Comment: It is clear from comment that this whole question is a complete nonsense. There is one issue if a person can't see PIDs. And another issue if a person can't see a process listed.  Each has a simple solution. And one could have both those issues together.    If you can't see PIDs, then you choose the option for the PID column. And if you can't see a process listed then you click to show processes from all users.  There no such issue of not being able to see the PID of a particular process.

Comment: @barlop, fwiw I've got this problem right now, taskmanager doesn't show some processes which are listed by `query process USERNAME`. When I log in a further user has processes listed, these processes aren't shown in the listing; it's not that I can't see the PIDs, the PIDs of other processes show. SysInternals `procexp64` shows the processes but they can't all be killed as killing stihost restarts them all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For example:

```
tasklist /FI "PID eq 736" /FO TABLE
```

Best tools to investigate Win processes I know about are from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)

Try using `Process Explorer` or `TcpView`

Comment: do i need to type this in the command prompt?

Comment: Yes, this is command line tool. Of course change the number of process id.

Comment: i just would like to make sure if my understanding is correct.

Comment: does that mean i write it like this: "tasklist /FI "4 eq 736" /FO TABLE"... where did you get the 736?

Comment: Sorry, I've made typo. Filter should be "PID eq 736". 736 is example PID number. Ok, you obtain your pid that you would like to investigate further (with netstat -ao I've assumed). Then you type: tasklist /FI "PID eq YOUR_PID_NO_FROM_NETSTAT" and then other options (I added output formatting for instance). You can look up tasklist switches with `tasklist /?`

Comment: in "PID eq 736" PID is a part of the tasklist filter. It is not placeholder for your pid.  "PID eq 4" in your case.

Comment: thanks Casual Coder. i was able to see now what that PID represents. I'm not sure what is this 4 "System" doing as it shows "Established"

Comment: Sysinternals utilities are really helpful in such cases. Is it local connection (on loopback) or remote one? Perhaps M$ stuff? (like Windows Update etc.)

Comment: how will I know that this local or remote?

Comment: Look at `Foreign Address` column in `netstat` output.

Comment: +1 for Sysinternals. In my case, it was an orphan process that outlived a log-off. I had to restart my PC to kill, as I don't have admin access to kill this process.

Comment: A)seems to work exactly the same without `/FO table`. B)And this command line solution is unnecessarily technical, when the OP had the issue with task manager and should simply have clicked that button to show all processes and it'd show the process., and picked the option to show the PID and it'd show the PIDs for processes listed. The command line option you mention is no better than what task manager would show.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need Task Manager for tracking this. Just run `netstat -b` which will display the exe associated with the PID..

Comment: ...but then how to stop that process?

Comment: @Arjan `taskkill /f /im blah.exe`

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from comment that this whole question is a complete nonsense. There is one issue if a person can't see PIDs. And another issue if a person can't see a process listed.  Each has a simple solution. And one could have both those issues together.    If you can't see PIDs, then you choose the option for the PID column. And if you can't see a process listed then you click to show processes from all users.

There no such issue of not being able to see the PID of a particular process. The questioner is simply not describing things properly.

To elaborate.- I'm going to first answer the question for what it says.  But a comment suggests that the questioner is not describing things well and actually he can't see the process listed at all (not just he can't see the PID), and that's because he hasn't clicked the button in task manager to show processes from all users to make it show all processes.

For the question of if somebody can't see the PIDs.

To see PID numbers in task manager, first CTRL-SHIFT+ESC will bring up task manager (this is quicker than ctrl-alt-delete).

To show the PID of each process, click `view->choose columns->pid` and click ok

PID is the second item in the list of columns you can select.

In the questioner's case, he can't see the process, he should click "show processes from all users" Then he will see the process and of course, with PID.

The Questioner could use the tasklist command which is in the accepted answer, or he could simply use task manager and click that mentioned button.

Bear in mind though that he won't be able to kill the process with PID 4, which is the PID of the process he is looking for info on.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The OP said that some PID's seen in netstat does not show up in taskmanager.  The question is what happened to those missing PID's.

Comment: @Stefan no the OP said he saw some processes PIDs in netstat, and he can't see their PIDs in task manager.  He didn't say that in task manager he sees PIDs for some processes and not others (And if he had heant that then i've never even heard of such a problem, it's questionable whether such a problem even exists, is that what you think he meant? you could say the OP was ambiguous).

Comment: No, you are incorrect. He said "When I checked it in my Task Manager, I couldn't find THOSE PID numbers."  And yes, the problem does exist - that is the reason I found this thread - because that is exactly what happened to me.  It would be very, much more strange if the problem was that he could not view the PID column in task manager.  THAT is something I would never have heard about :)

Comment: @Stefan  I know he said he couldn't find those PID numbers, that may be because he can't see any. To give you an example, I just looked up task manager on youtube and both examples I saw, one for Win XP and one for Win7, both aren't showing PID  so it's a really classic 'issue' for task manager to not be showing PID (was probably a default in XP and possibly even in 7 judging by the following pic), https://i.imgur.com/E6TtgVc.png      Please show a pic   Please include a link to a pic showing what you describe of some process IDs showing and some not showing 'cos i've never seen that before.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216881/pid-exists-in-netstat-but-does-not-exist-in-task-manager

Comment: @Stefan That is different, He says the process itself doesn't show in task manager.  really this questioner(tintincutes) is really unclear because I think it's impossible for just one process to not show a PID in task manager.  There are two possibilities re what he can mean by a PID not showing A)All processes don't show PID, because PID column isn't selected B)The process itself isn't showing.    Judging by a comment of his, in reply to a suggestion to show PID column, he saw the PID of 4, which is another issue, where he then sees the PID but it doesn't help him. And.... (cntd)

Comment: (cntd) It looks like he hadn't clicked  "show all processes from all users", when he did that, he saw the process, and of course the PID(since as per the suggestion he had showed the PID column). Really a very badly asked question

Comment: (cntd) The OP is asking wrong if he says he can't see the PIDs when he meant he can't see the processes.

Comment: (cntd)  So I did answer exactly what the OP asked. But the OP's wasn't describing things right and actually he should've asked something else, i've now addressed both things in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some PID's you can see and some others you cannot. For example, I could not see PID=4 which is System. However I could see many others. Of course, I do not know the reason why.
You can use the following command to see them. I have shown here a small portion of the output.

```
C:\Windows\system32>netstat -nao

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       840
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8112
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:554            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7880
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1521           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1080
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1160
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3500           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:6600           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2216
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1080
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8081           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8112
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8090           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8093           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3904
  TCP    0.0.0.0:18050          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:30761          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1968
  TCP    0.0.0.0:32843          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:32844          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       544
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1012
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       648
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       380
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49156          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1484
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49202          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       700
```

Comment: You hadn't clicked "show processes from all users" then you'd see the processes with PID=4 in task manager.

Comment: also you'd know that if you'd read the other answers, like my one from 2010

Answer (score 0):

go to http://live.sysinternals.com/ and download procexp.exe (process explorer) this will provide you with all the relevant details.

otheriwse you can find it in task manager by viewing the column for process ID

Answer (score 0):

For those who try to make sense from `netstat -o`. It just report invalid PID. **Don't try to make any sense from `-o` option. It is unreliable.**

I reproduce issue 100% with Cygwin:

```
cygrunsrv -I lighttpd -t manual -p /usr/sbin/lighttpd.exe --args "-f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf" -c / -d "Lighttpd" -f "Local lighttpd"

sc start lighttpd

ps -a | grep lighttpd
     3989       1    3988      23104  ?             18 12:07:30 /usr/sbin/lighttpd

NETSTAT -a -n -o | grep :80
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       28916

tasklist /FI "PID eq 28916" /FO TABLE
INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.

kill 3988

NETSTAT -a -n -o | grep :80
### EMPTY!!!!!!
```

Probably `cygwin.dll` do some magic with PID which confuses `netstat -o`.

I have no luck with `-b` either:

```
netstat -natbo

  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       14220
 [System]
```

What is `[System]`? Actually it is Cygwin's Lighttpd run as system service with different PID ))

**So there is a bug in Windows `netstat`  implementation.**

**PS** I'm on Win 10 ver 2004 build 10.0.19041.867 (March 2021).

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with Cyber Hackers that have gained access to someone's computer through Pier to pier services such as Log-me-in ect.. and also with individuals that give out they're account information to others to actively share purchased content with another user via Xbox Live services. During which the Console is now made their home console, the hacker uses the IP address to grant permissions and can change the administrator rights or the victim to deny the ability to view or change a PID file path.. this literally locks the ability to see PID information from other Users by using Task Manager.

The get around for this is to directly use the function to identify the listening port used by the hacker and shown via CMD's function to use Netstat -ano to show the complete list of active connections. Each PID can then be investigated to identify and know if the connection is supposed to exist or not. In the event admistrator rights are revoked, as we also see commonly with select ISP providers that do not support VPN connections.. IE: Frontier Communications.. They will block services and restrict access to viewing such path directories. or file extensions ect.. very similar to a social media outlet's ability to ban someone from viewing someone domain like on Facebook.. User doesn't want so and so to see his/her page.. block.. this uses the same functions to block access to reading or executing the request and receives an message as it's scripted on Facebook.. just in this case, no error message was designate. So the denial happens without an error or known registry response.

For the PID path that doesn't appear when someone has Locked you from Administrator privileges to identify them or Taskkill the PID path directory Established.. You can search your Task List using CMD tasklist /FI "PID eq (desired PID)" /FO TABLE and it will identify which Task it is attached too...

In my case it was Tasklist /FI "PID eq 20114" /FO Table
I hit enter and it said plain as day that it was Game Bar and attached to it so I knew it was someone Using Microsofts Xbox Game Bar/Xbox App, they were looking up my gamertags IP address which I paid to have Blacklisted btw.. and they then persisted to hack me and attached themselves to my Console, my phone, and my Computer. I was then able to Taskkill "PID eq 20114" /F and bam... they're gone and my computer, and my phone works again.. but not my Xbox... now it won't even turn on. Still resolving that issue.